# prisma throws exception right on running in debug mode

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, nestjs, prisma

i am running a nest project in debug mode inside visual studio code

on run it throws this exception

`Exception has occurred: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getConfig')at Object.getConfig`

[image]

at the same time, the solution along with prisma runs normally without debug mode

here is my `launch.json` file

```json
{

    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
    
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Debug Nest Framework",
            "args": ["${workspaceFolder}/src/main.ts"],
            "runtimeArgs": ["--nolazy", "-r", "ts-node/register"],
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "protocol": "inspector"
        }
    ]
}
```

this is the root `AppModule`

```js
/*imports...*/
@Module({
  imports: [ControllersModule, ConfigModule.forRoot({
    isGlobal: true,
    envFilePath: `.env`
    // ignoreEnvFile: process.env.ENV !== `DEV`,
  }), AuthModule, UsersModule, ScheduleModule.forRoot()
  
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

`prisma.service.ts`  code :

```js
import { Injectable, OnModuleInit, OnModuleDestroy } from '@nestjs/common'
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'

@Injectable()
export class PrismaService
  extends PrismaClient
  implements OnModuleInit, OnModuleDestroy
{
  async onModuleInit() {
    await this.$connect()
  }

  async onModuleDestroy() {
    await this.$disconnect()
  }
}
```

Comment: Check (add to your question) your code in prisma.service.ts around line 5

Comment: I tried reproducing the error based on what you provided, but everything seems to run fine for me. Would it be possible to provide any kind of reproduction? Preferably some kind of github repo that can I could run to reproduce the error.

Comment: i would appriciate that a lot, i have pushed it onto git hub here is the repos link : ```https://github.com/habhabsafi/subjects-backend-public.git``` it is public. i am also having an issue that the ts files wont compile on ```npm start``` unless i execute ```tsc``` before it. with much thanks !